# Fixed element not showing because of height

Tags: css

I have a fixed element (image) between some divs the problem is on some resolutions the element doesn't show is in the bottom of the page (if I fullscreen the page I can see it) on my resolution is ok.

How can I position the fixed element to be seen regardless the height of the monitor is displayed ?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span5" onclick="showVideo(5);" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="./preview/pre5.jpg" style="height:95px; width : 220px;">

            <div class="textu" id="prez" style="font-weight:bold;">
                Gothaer AD 2013
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span5" onclick="showVideo(6);" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="./preview/ebay.jpg" style="height:95px; width : 220px;">

            <div class="textu" id="prez" style="font-weight:bold;">
                Ebay AD 2012
            </div>
        </div><img onclick="showAll();" src="./img/updown.png" style=
        "cursor:pointer;position:fixed;padding-left:8px;padding-top:33px;">

        <div class="span5" onclick="showVideo(7);" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="./preview/silva.jpg" style="height:95px; width : 220px;">

            <div class="textu" id="prez" style="font-weight:bold;">
                Silva 2012
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span5" onclick="showVideo(8);" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="./preview/balenaziua.jpg" style=
            "height:95px; width : 220px;">

            <div class="textu" id="prez" style="font-weight:bold;">
                Alfredo Foods TVC
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

updown.png is the element!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set position of your image with respect to the page if you want it to be visible always:

for example you can add following css to your image:

```
left:10%;
bottom:10%;
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/AS5a3/

Comment: works great thanks, still have one problem how can i prevent the image showing in other divs than the main div it was desigined ?

Comment: i didn't understand your comment. please elaborate.

Comment: The divs I pasted the code are at the bottom of the page on a smaller resolution the image I have set style to fixed appears on images on top witch they are from another div. I want this image to be displayed only in a div I want.is there any workarround ?

Comment: so you want the image with fixed position to be fixed at its place but at the same time shouldn't appear over another images. isn't that?

Comment: yep should appear only in a single div

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/AS5a3/1/ if no then please create a new question and attach an image describing your requirement.